# Create/Update Global Value Set using Tooling API

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, callout, tooling-api

Can someone tell me how to create and update Global value set using tooling API?
No sure what so send in request body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel, you can develop code to create/update GlobalValueSet.

By using tooling api, we will need to make http request to endpoint (/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet). While case of insert, no need to provide picklist value set it. But while updating that we must need to provide as below.

**Insert GlobalValueset:**

```
//you would need to update picklist values here
String fieldDef = '{"Metadata":{"customValue":[{"color":null,"default":false,"description":null,"isActive":null,"label":"Ayubb","urls":null,"valueName":"Ayub"},{"color":null,"default":false,"description":null,"isActive":null,"label":"Ansari","urls":null,"valueName":"Ansari"}],"description":null,"masterLabel":"GemsofMyLife","sorted":false,"urls":null},"FullName":"Gems_of_My_Life"}';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(fieldDef);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet');
req.setMethod('POST');
Http httpreq = new Http();
HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

**Update GlobalValueSet**

```
String fieldDef = '{"Metadata":{"customValue":[{"color":null,"default":false,"description":null,"isActive":null,"label":"Ayubb","urls":null,"valueName":"Ayub"},{"color":null,"default":false,"description":null,"isActive":null,"label":"Ansari","urls":null,"valueName":"Ansari"}],"description":null,"masterLabel":"GemsofMyLife","sorted":false,"urls":null},"FullName":"Gems_of_My_Life"}';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(fieldDef);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt90000000XZHw?_HttpMethod=PATCH');**//replace id with your GlobalPicklist Id**
req.setMethod('POST');
//req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override','PATCH');
Http httpreq = new Http();
HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: Thanks Ayub.. but i am running a SOQL.. How to retrive multiple global value set... /services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q=Select+id,MasterLabel,Description,fullname,metadata+from+GlobalValueSet+limit+1... If you use this it will set limit to 1 but its not working without limit 1.

Comment: In order to update, you only need one Id...so i dont think it make sense to query multiple records...or provide where clause...

Comment: I also want to get full list of the global value sets with the values... Thats why i was asking... Is it possible?

Comment: @Arteezy  ..you can do that..but do not pass Fullname and Metadata in Query...it does not support bulk records in query....use MasterLabel field if you need to print somewhere...here would be query to retrieve all:  /services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q=Select+id,MasterLabel,Description+from+GlobalValueSet

Comment: Why do we have isActive as Null, can we use it to Activate and Deactivate the picklist values from global picklist?

Comment: Of course, you can use to activate and deactivate but I have never gave a try! would recommend to get metadata from an existing picklist value using workbench then update accordingly.

Comment: I get the error :"The requested resource does not exist"
my url is :{baseURL}/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet

Comment: verify same url in workbench --> Rest Api. There may b some syntax issue, you can find that while making call in workbench.

Answer (score 4):

With things like this the documentation is the place to start - [GlobalValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_globalvalueset.htm).

We can then jump over to [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) to try it out with the REST API:

GET `/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt7F000000cIqx`

I got the GlobalValueSet ID (Keyprefix [0Nt](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#0Nt)) straight from the UI when making a test record.

The gave me the raw response:

```
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "GlobalValueSet",
    "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt7F000000cIqxSAE"
  },
  "Metadata" : {
    "customValue" : [ {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "First",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "First"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Second",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Second"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Third",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Third"
    } ],
    "description" : null,
    "masterLabel" : "Test",
    "sorted" : false,
    "urls" : null
  },
  "FullName" : "Test",
  "Id" : "0Nt7F000000cIqxSAE",
  "DeveloperName" : "Test",
  "MasterLabel" : "Test",
  "Description" : null,
  "NamespacePrefix" : null,
  "ManageableState" : "unmanaged",
  "CreatedDate" : "2018-05-08T10:45:35.000+0000",
  "CreatedById" : "0057F000002XauUQAS",
  "LastModifiedDate" : "2018-05-08T10:45:35.000+0000",
  "LastModifiedById" : "0057F000002XauUQAS"
}
```

With some slight alterations that can be replayed back to create the new record.

1. Trim out the `attributes`
2. Trim out any other top level fields except the `Metadata` and `FullName`
3. Modify the `FullName` and `masterLabel`
4. Modify the `customValue`'s as required.

Use Workbench to POST to `/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet`.

E.g.

```
{
  "Metadata" : {
    "customValue" : [ {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "First",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "First"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Second",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Second"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Third",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Third"
    } ],
    "description" : null,
    "masterLabel" : "Test2",
    "sorted" : false,
    "urls" : null
  },
  "FullName" : "Test2"
}
```

Voilà -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way for adding the new values to all the Picklist values whose are dependent on Record types?

Comment: @Amjadkhan I'd recommend asking a new question to help determine that. You can link it to this question and include anything you have tried already.

Comment: @DanielBallinger When doing a PATCH http method REST call to update the valueName of a picklist value I get the "Duplicate label" error.  Do you know if picklist value's  API name or its label can be updated (using the REST http ) ?

Comment: @TickleMe I haven't explicitly tried. Maybe raise a new question with what you tried and link it back to this one.