# Update Global Value Set using Tooling API

Tags: apex, metadata, tooling-api

I'm trying to update a global value set, using Tooling API.

My issue is when I update the global picklist -  if I have values in it that does not exist in my new JSON - it's putting them as inActive.

I wish to update the values - if the API is the same, or create new ones if it does not exist in the picklist, and remain the existing values.

What  did so far -

```
  public class RootObjectMeta{
        Metadata metadata;
        public String fullName;
    }

    public class Metadata {
        public List<CustomValue> customValue;
        public Object description;
        public String masterLabel;
        public Boolean sorted;
    }

    public class CustomValue {
        public Object color;
        // public Boolean default;
        public Object description;
        public Object isActive;
        public String label;  
        public String valueName;
    }
```

//Having a service which returns the picklist values I need from another system - I inserted it to a Map<String,String> (Value , label) - called : codeandDesctions

```
 RootObjectMeta rootObjMeta = new RootObjectMeta();

        rootObjMeta.fullName = 'Reasons';
    
        Metadata m = new Metadata();
        m.description = 'Test';
        m.masterLabel = 'Reasons';
        m.sorted = false;

        List<CustomValue> cv = new List<CustomValue>();
        CustomValue cv1;

        
        for(String s : codeandDesctions.keySet()){ //(Value - label Map)

                cv1 = new CustomValue();
                cv1.color = null;
                //cv1.default = false;
                cv1.description = null;
                cv1.label=codeandDesctions.get(s);
                cv1.valueName = s;
                
                cv.add(cv1);
          
        }
        
        
        
    m.CustomValue = cv;
    rootObjMeta.metadata = m;

    String stringJson = JSON.serializePretty(rootObjMeta);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(stringJson);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt1l0000008g91?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    Http httpreqMeta = new Http();
    HttpResponse res  = httpreqMeta.send(req);
    system.debug(res.getBody());
```

For example:

if I have a global picklist with the values :  label: code 1 , value: 1

and the JSON with the picklist value have the values:  code 1 => 1 , code 2 => 2

The label: code 2 => 2 - will appear next to my existing code 1 => 1.

But if the json return only  code 2 => 2, it will make code 1 => 1 inactive.

What I wish to achieve:
for scenario 2 : code 2 => 2 will be added and code 1 => 1 will stay active.

I got helped from: [Create/Update Global Value Set using Tooling API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217309/create-update-global-value-set-using-tooling-api)

Hope this is clear enough,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any values not specified will be made invalid. That's how the API works. You need to first retrieve the values, then update the list.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox