# How can I create API names in global picklist with 500 values in a fast way?

Tags: soql, picklist, administration, automation, global-picklist

I have file like this with about 500 values:

[image: file example]

I am creating Global Value Set.

Column A is for Label and column B is for API names. Both columns contains about 500 records.

I know that I can create a global picklist with only labels by copying the first column from Excel to Global Value Set, but then I need to change manually (or in Webstorm) 500 API names.

How could I do this in a fast way? Does exist some Salesforce feature, SOQL command or Apex code which enable to edit API names without doing long manual, repetitive work?

Comment: You can create it with metadata api and deploy to salesforce

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create/Update Global Value Set using Tooling API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217309/create-update-global-value-set-using-tooling-api)